# ADF databricks python activity to pick python script from blob storage not from dbfs

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I'm running databricks python activity from the Azure data factory. I want to pick the python/shell script from Azure blob-storage/data-lake instead for dbfs path. My current ADF databricks python activity is not allowing without 'dbfs:/'.

Could you please help me here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried mounting the datalake to the dbfs ?

Comment: mounting will work in this way 'https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html'
do you have any implementation for this to mount blob to dbfs system to pick the python scripts ?

Comment: Try mounting your Azure storage to your Databricks Workspace using the link you found. Upload your script to the storage account and put the dbfs path on Data Factory : ``` dbfs:/mnt/path_to_file_on_storage_account/file.py ```

Comment: Try mounting your Azure storage to your Databricks Workspace using the link you found. Upload your script to the storage account and put the dbfs path on Data Factory : ``` dbfs:/mnt/path_to_file_on_storage_account/file.py ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only dbfs file path is supported in the Databricks Python activity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python#databricks-python-activity-properties

you need to think of other methods for uploading the python file to dbfs using databricks cli, potentially through your cicd pipeline also.